# How to auto unHide next column if previous column contains cell = "X"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So far I have two functions working in the google script editor - the first works, the second does not.

```
       function HideColumn() //trigger is set to open

      {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");

       var datarange = s.hideColumns(34); //this will hide Column AH
      }




      function unHideColumn() //trigger is set to edit

    { 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
      var range = sheet.getRange("AG2");


     {

     if (range === ("14. Ineliglble")) sheet.unhideColumn("AH");

      }
     }
```

Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DJTmKqaiYWdeoNxTWIawTE-nzI_mcIdbq9VEiCJz6OM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Questions about non-working code should include details about the error message that you got. Reference [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [getActiveCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell()) should not have an argument.
2. When doing an equality comparison, you could use `==` or `===` not `=`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

See also https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for the above - very helpful: I have now fixed the syntax issue and no errors are returned - however the function does not trigger. The latest I have is: